# How to store java objects on Solr

Tags: java, solr, binary-data

I want to store java objects as part of the Solr document.
They don't need to be parsed or searched, only be returned as part of the document.
I can convert them to json or XML and store the text but I prefer something more efficient.
If I could use Java serialization and then add the binary blob to the document it could be ideal.
I'm aware of the option to convert the binary blob with base64 but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way.

Comment: Thanks for providing other excellent alternatives. My objects are very small and I would want to compare the performance of getting them back directly with the solr query results vs the database option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not share the opinions of the first two answers.

An additional database call can in some scenarios be completely unnecessary, Solr can act as a NoSQL database, too.

It can even use *compression* for some fields, which affects CPU cost, but saves some cache memory for some kind of binary data.

Take a look at [BinaryField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/schema/BinaryField.html) and the lazy loading field declarations within your schema.xml.

Comment: SOLR cannot use compression. That was deprecated some time ago. However you can compress a field yourself before sending it to SOLR are either a BinaryField or a base64 encoded string.

Comment: @Michael Dillon Thanks for pointing at that circumstance - it seems that my knowledge is a little bit outdated in that area

Answer (score 2):

As you can construct an id in Solr to pass with any document, you can store this object in other way (database for example) and query it as you get the id back from solr.

For example, we're storing web pages in Solr. When we index it, we're creating an id which match the id of a WebPage Object created by the ORM in the database

When a search is performed, we get the id back and load the java object from the database

No need to store it in solr (which has been made to store and index documents)

Comment: I agree Solr is not really designed as a persistence store, especially for binary objects.

Comment: I second that completely. Although I'm sure you could come up with some hack to put a serialized Java object into your Solr index, I wouldn't recommend it. Store it somewhere else. In the long run, using your Solr index this way will only hurt you. Performance will decrease, index size will increase, master/slave replication will take longer, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I've started with this option but wanted to compare the performance with the Solr only solution.